# Analytic Topology for Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have done basic topology till compactness and connectedness and I want to take the course on Algebraic Topology. I was wondering if Analytic topology is a must do or not and if I should be well versed with Cohomology before starting Algebraic Topology course. Some details:

My course on Analytic topology has:
Separation axioms. Subbases. Lindelöf and countably compact spaces. Seperable spaces. Filters and ultrafilters. Convergence in terms of filters. Tychonoff's theorem. Compactifications, in particular the Alexandroff One-Point Compactification and the Stone-Čech Compactification. Proper maps. Completeness, connectedness and local connectedness. Components and quasi-components. Urysohn's metrization theorem. Paracompactness. Stone's Theorem; that metric spaces are paracompact. Totally disconnected compact spaces and Stone duality.
Algebraic Topology has:
Brief introduction to categories and functors. Applications of homology theory: Invariance of dimension, Brower fixed point theorem.

Chain complexes of free Abelian groups and their homology. Short exact sequences. of chain complexes, the induced long exact sequence in homology, and naturality. The snake lemma, the five lemma, splitting properties for short exact sequences.

Simplicial homology via Delta complexes.

Singular homology of topological spaces, and functoriality. Relative homology. Chain homotopies, homotopy equivalences. Homotopy invariance and excision (details of proofs not examinable). Retractions, deformation retractions, quotients.

Mayer-Vietoris Sequence. Wedge sums, cones, suspensions, connected sums.

Degree of a self-map of a sphere. Application: the hairy ball theorem.

Cell complexes and cellular homology. Equivalence of simplicial, cellular and singular homology.

Cochains and cohomology of spaces. Cup products.

Künneth Theorem (without proof). Euler characteristic. Ext and Tor groups via free resolutions. (Co)homology with different coefficients. The Universal Coefficient Theorem (proof not examinable).

Topological manifolds and orientability. The fundamental class of an orientable, closed manifold and the degree of a map between manifolds of the same dimension. Poincaré duality (proof not examinable). Manifolds with boundary and Poincaré-Lefschetz duality (proof not examinable). Brief discussion of locally finite homology, and cohomology with compact supports. Cap product.

Alexander duality. Applications: knot complements, Jordan curve theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to be familiar with the contents of the analytic topology syllabus or cohomology before taking this algebraic topology course. This analytic topology course looks to be the sort of thing that is useful for analysts, logicians, and some topologists.

The one thing I would suggest when you sign up for algebraic topology is to ask the instructor if you are expected to be familiar with the fundamental group; it doesn't look necessary, but it's worth asking.